# Navigation Bar text aligning backwards (CSS)

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm in the process of developing my first website and I'm having an issue with the Navigation Bar. I'm using CSS rules to align the bar but unfortunately when I set the rules to `float:right;` my text is floating right but it’s lining up  backwards on the bar.  How can I float the text over to the right and align the text correctly?

```css
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.nav {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  color: orange;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to float the `ul` list, not individual list items `li`.

Setting `float: right` on `li` allows the first list item to align to the right first and then the rest of the items take their positions similarly. It caused the direction of the list from right to left.

```css
.nav ul {
  float: right; /* Added */
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  /* float: right; Removed */ 
}
.nav {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  color: orange;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: oh.. same answer we have. :) Let me delete my one.

Comment: @CodeRomeos There is no problem if we have the same answer ;) Just a matter of seconds.