# Problems aligning a nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues aligning a nav bar on my mate's site.

I'm trying to have his company on floated to the left, where the navigation items floated to the right. However, when using the code below, they are aligned in the reverse order.

I've used this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768668/navigation-bar-text-aligning-backwards-css) to help rectify the problem, but it doesn't seem to help.

HTML

```
<div id = "navbar">
    <a id = "logo">Rob Moore LTD</h3>
    <a class = "nav" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a class = "nav" href="#about">About</a>
    <a class = "nav" href="#services">Services</a>
    <a class = "nav" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
    <a class = "nav" href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navbar {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#navbar a {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar .nav {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#navbar #logo {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this behaviour before, I think it has something to do with the float:right, so you can wrap those a tags with a div as follows:

```
<div id = "navbar">
<div class="wrapper">
<a id = "logo">Rob Moore LTD</h3>
<a class = "nav" href="#home">Home</a>
<a class = "nav" href="#about">About</a>
<a class = "nav" href="#services">Services</a>
<a class = "nav" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
<a class = "nav" href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
```

and in your css:

```
.wrapper{
    float:right
}

#navbar a {
display: block;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-left: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Or you could just change the order of a tags in the html. Hope it helps.